# Multi thread in Python search engine crawler causing a hang

Tags: multithreading, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to teach myself programming and I've run into a wall with multithreads, I'm using it try and speed up my google crawler, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
# Requires a search string and page numbers to scan
def google(search_string, start):
    temp                = []
    url                 = 'http://www.google.com/search'
    payload             = { 'q' : search_string, 'start' : start }
    my_headers          = { 'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/11.0' }
    r                   = requests.get( url, params = payload, headers = my_headers )
    r.text.encode('utf-8')
    soup                = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'html.parser' )
    h3tags              = soup.find_all( 'h3', class_='r' )
        # Prints and writes output of scrapped URLs
    with open(str("test.txt"), "w") as out_15:
        for h3 in h3tags:
            try:
                print( re.search('url\?q=(.+?)\&sa', h3.a['href']).group(1) )
                temp.append( re.search('url\?q=(.+?)\&sa', h3.a['href']).group(1) )
            except:
                continue
    return temp
```

and

```
def main():
    start               = timer()
    result              = []
    search              = input ("Please enter Dork String(<dork - no include inurl:> <extra-terms>):")
    pages               = int(input ("how many URL's would you like?:"))
    pages               = pages / 10
    processes           = int(input ("How many threads (<= 8):"))
    make_request        = partial( google, search )
    pagelist            = [ str(x*10) for x in range( 0, int(pages) ) ]
    #Multithreads ??
    with Pool(processes) as p:
        tmp = p.map(make_request, pagelist)
    for x in tmp:
        result.extend(x)
    result              = list( set( result ) )
    print ( *result, sep = '/n' )
    #stats
    print ( '\nTotal URLs Scraped : %s ' % str( len( result ) ) )
    print ( 'Script Execution Time : %s ' % ( timer() - start, ) )
```

Comment: Just an FYI, it won't take long for Google to block you even if you get this working.